# Inequality on length of intervals

Tags: measure-theory, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

> Let $n\ge 1$ and $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^{n}$ is a set of non-degenerate
>   subintervals of $[0,1]$. Then show that :
>   $$ \overline\sum \dfrac{1}{|I_j\cup I_k|}\geq n^2$$
>   Here $\overline\sum$ denotes summing over $j,k$ with $I_j\cap I_k\neq \emptyset$.

This is a problem from the Miklos Schweitzer competition. But, I don't have an idea about it, can someone give me a hint or something? An idea on how to proceed would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're fixing a $k$ but then the sum is over pairs of indices $j,k$? Did you mean to just sum over $j$?

Comment: You typed the question wrong. See http://www.bolyai.hu/SCH_angol_2014.pdf

Comment: My first attempt would be to use induction.

Comment: Presumably $|I_j\cup I_k|$ means the length of the interval rather than its cardinality.

Comment: Yes, it means the length. @MichaelAlbanese, and yeah I made a typo, it was confusing using $I_i$ and $I_j$, so I switched variable names. Thanks.

Comment: If $I_j\cap I_k = \emptyset$, it isn't too hard to show that $\frac{1}{|I_j|} + \frac{1}{|I_k|} \geq 4$. Not sure if it helps; just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: In fact, if $I_{j_1}, \dots, I_{j_m}$ are pairwise disjoint, then $\frac{1}{|I_{j_1}|} + \dots + \frac{1}{|I_{j_m}|} \geq m^2$.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3692478&#p3692478) for a very elegant solution.

Moreover, [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=2&cid=152&) you can find a list of the problems from this competition which have been asked on the AoPS forum (but some of them have not been solved there).